# Nested IF THEN statement with MAX condition in R

Tags: r, excel, syntax, formula

I have a df structured with the following columns:

`RowID, UserID, Event`

There are multiple rows per userID and many different user IDs. Event will be a whole number >=0.

I need R to look for the MAXIMUM row ID where the event for a specific user ID is greater than 0 and then label any ensuing rows for that userID as "after" in a new column (else, label it "before").

Example:

```
rowID, userID, event, output  
1, 999, 0, before  
2, 999, 1, before  
3, 999, 0, after
```

I'm totally new to R so not even sure where to start to achieve this. I know how to do it just fine in Excel but my CSV is too large to do the calculation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky task with base R functionality. This solution uses the `dplyr` package, which I would recommend learning if you are getting into R programming.

Generate some data:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(rowID = 1:5, userID = c(999,999,999,111,111), event = c(0,1,0,1,1))
df    
  rowID userID event
1     1    999     0
2     2    999     1
3     3    999     0
4     4    111     1
5     5    111     1
```

Filter rows to only those with `event` equal to 1, group by user ID, and calculate maximum row ID.

```
df %>% filter(event == 1) %>% group_by(userID) %>% summarise(maxR = max(rowID))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  userID  maxR
   <dbl> <dbl>
1    111     5
2    999     2
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer OPs question and his expected output. Also I wouldn't call reproducing your result in base R tricky: `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df, df$userID), function(x) x[order(x$rowID, decreasing = T), ][x$event == 1, ][1, -3]))` but that's just a side-note. The `dplyr` syntax is definitely neater;-)

Answer (score 0):

Below you will find a step, by step approach, how to calculate the `output` column.

Note that I added also a User without event greater than 0, which leads to `NA` as the maximum `rowID` and is handled in extra assignment.

```
> df <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep=",", text = "rowID, userID, event   
+ 1, 999, 0   
+ 2, 999, 1   
+ 3, 999, 0
+ 4, 100, 0
+ 5, 100, 1
+ 6, 100, 0
+ 7, 100, 1
+ 8, 100, 0
+ 9, 100, 0
+ 10, 101, 0
+ 11, 101, 0
+ 12, 102, 1
+ ")
> 
> ## filter events
> df1 <- df[df$event > 0,]
> ## calculate max rowID per user
> max <- setNames(aggregate(df1$rowID, by = list(df1$userID), max) , c("userID", "maxRowID"))
> max
  userID maxRowID
1    100        7
2    102       12
3    999        2
> 
> ## merge the max to the dataframe
> mrg <- merge(x = df, y = max, by = "userID" , all.x = TRUE)
> ## establish the original order
> mrg <- mrg[with(mrg, order(rowID)), ]
> mrg
   userID rowID event maxRowID
10    999     1     0        2
11    999     2     1        2
12    999     3     0        2
1     100     4     0        7
2     100     5     1        7
5     100     6     0        7
6     100     7     1        7
3     100     8     0        7
4     100     9     0        7
7     101    10     0       NA
8     101    11     0       NA
9     102    12     1       12
> 
> ## calculate output, 
> output <- ifelse( mrg$rowID >  mrg$maxRowID,'after','before')
> ## consider also case with no event > 0
> output[is.na(output)] <- 'before'
> 
> ## add the output column to the original dataframe
> df$output <- output
> df
   rowID userID event output
1      1    999     0 before
2      2    999     1 before
3      3    999     0  after
4      4    100     0 before
5      5    100     1 before
6      6    100     0 before
7      7    100     1 before
8      8    100     0  after
9      9    100     0  after
10    10    101     0 before
11    11    101     0 before
12    12    102     1 before
>
```